# Is there any way to know if a certain button has been pressed in a certain location inside a div element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm trying to make a todo list app similar to Trello. I have a button that when pressed turns into an input element, gets a "To Do Task" item and adds that to a list. This is achieved by this piece of code:

```
function createCardBoxNode(title){

/*HTML looks like: 
<div class="task-card">
                <div class="writings">
                    <p class="title">Tasks To Do</p>
                    <ul id="tasks">
                        <li>Task 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-add-task"> 
                    Add New Task...
                </button>
                <input....>
</div>
*/
  var containerBox = createElement('div', {class:'task-card'});
  var writingPartBox = createWritingAreaNode(title);
  var newTaskBtn = createElement('button', {class:'btn-add-task show'},'Add New Task...');
  var newTaskInput = createElement('input', {class:'new-task hide', type:'text', placeholder:'New Task'});
  
//When 'add new task' is clicked, make it an input area
  newTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    newTaskBtn.classList.remove('show');
    newTaskBtn.classList.add('hide');
    
    newTaskInput.classList.remove('hide');
    newTaskInput.classList.add('show');
    newTaskInput.focus();
  });
  
// when input is entered, that's a new "To Do Task" so add it to the list
  newTaskInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13){
      // If Enter is pressed  
      var newTask = createListItems(newTaskInput.value);
      var listArea = document.getElementById('tasks');
      
      listArea.appendChild(newTask);
      
      newTaskInput.classList.remove('show');
      newTaskInput.classList.add('hide');
      newTaskInput.value = '';

      newTaskBtn.classList.remove('hide');
      newTaskBtn.classList.add('show');
    }
  });
  

  containerBox.appendChild(writingPartBox);
  containerBox.appendChild(newTaskBtn);
  containerBox.appendChild(newTaskInput);

  return containerBox;

}
```

This works fine until I add another Card at the same time and decide to add new tasks to the second card. Then every task gets added to the first card. I wonder if there is any way to check if the "input" that's being sent is going to a specific card checking the card's title. I don't have any limits on how many tasks can be added to each card, and don't want to add that. I also want the user to be able to work on two separate cards at the same time. As a beginner, I also want to fix this using only JavaScript. I hope I've explained the issue well enough.

Edit:
I have tried doing this:

```
if (document.querySelector('.title').innerText === title){
        var newTask = createListItems(newTaskInput.value);
        var listArea = document.getElementById('tasks');

        listArea.appendChild(newTask);
        
        newTaskInput.classList.remove('show');
        newTaskInput.classList.add('hide');
        newTaskInput.value = '';

        newTaskBtn.classList.remove('hide');
        newTaskBtn.classList.add('show');
```

But then I cannot add anything new to the second box.

Comment: Also tried with the "e.key" solution since the keyCode is depricated, that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you use the `<ul>` with the same id for different cards.

First of all, change your markup and replace `<ul id="tasks">` with `<ul class="tasks-list">`

```html
<div class="task-card">
    <div class="writings">
        <p class="title">Tasks To Do</p>

        <ul class="tasks-list"> <!-- !!! here !!! -->
            <li>Task 1</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <button class="btn-add-task"> 
        Add New Task...
    </button>
    <input....>
</div>
```

and then change that selector in your `keyup` handler:

```js
//...

var listArea = containerBox.querySelector('.tasks-list');

// ...
```

Also, it would be better to declare

```js
var listArea = containerBox.querySelector('.tasks-list');;
```

outside your handler.

Comment: Thank you. What you said didn't work, but I fixed it on my own. The trick is to not select anything, because anytime you do - it will select the first one. I just needed to combine two functions and append it straight into my ul element.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own.

The trick is to not select anything at all. Everytime you queryselect anything, or get an element using it's ID - it will select the first element with that id or class.

What I ended up doing is to combine two of my functions, have a function generate my

and then just straight up append the list items into that ul. No selection whatsoever.